# Exception 'NSJSONReadingAssumeTopLevelDictionary and NSJSONReadingAllowFragments cannot be set at the same time'

Tags: ios, swift, nsjsonserialization, ios15, xcode13

After upgrading an Xcode to 13.0 version and recompiling my app with it on a device I started getting this exception:

**libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException**
*dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib*

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'NSJSONReadingAssumeTopLevelDictionary and NSJSONReadingAllowFragments cannot be set at the same time'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

It seems that the problem is with new option `topLevelDictionaryAssume` added in `JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions`, available only for ios15.

**What I've tried:**
I've checked all places where I had .allowFragments and replaced it with `topLevelDictionaryAssume`. It didn't help.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: In Swift you don't need `.allowFragments` at all if the expected object is a collection type. And even if it's not an array or dictionary in iOS13+ the framework is able to recognize fragments anyway.

Comment: i have to support ios10 and above

Comment: Again, if the expected type is a dictionary you can omit the `options` parameter, even in iOS 10. `.allowFragments` is only for a single string or number.

Comment: I got rid of all non-nil options in `[NSJSONSerialization dataWithObject]` and it seemed to work. Thank you.